# Getting the sub category

Tags: categories, terms

I have custom post types that are using sub-categories. I can't figure out how to display the sub-category slug. I am trying to make the sub-category name a class name, but it keeps returning "unrecognized", which isn't right because it is a subcategory. Here's the code:

```
<?php 
  $categories = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'menu_category', $cat_args);
  $args = array('parent' => $caregory->term_id);
  $sub_cats = get_categories( $args );
?>
<div class="menu-item isotope-box-nested <?php foreach($sub_cats as $sub_cat) echo $sub_cat->slug ?>">
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong her?

Comment: What output are you getting? Also, have you tried simply using `post_class()`?

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about the post_class() function. That did it! If you want to post as answer, I'll mark it as an answer. Thanks @belinus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `post_class()`, it will echo out your classes using just about everything it has on the post.

If you need to manipulate it, `get_post_class()` function can be used.